# I'm confused about rel="canonical" tag for home pages

Tags: html

I read point five on this URL: http://moz.com/blog/duplicate-content-in-a-post-panda-world and am really confused.

Do I need to add the rel="canonical" to my index.htm file of my website?

Comment: do you understand what canonicalisation itself is, and how it applies to websites?

Comment: Perhaps not. I've googled it a bit but none of what I read is clear.  I just don't wAnt to be negatively impacted for duplicate content. Can you advise me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to add the rel="canonical" to my index.htm file of my
>   website?

In your case, because you don't yet understand what canonicalisation is yet, I would advise **not** to use the tag - until you understand its meaning.

the `rel=canonical` meta tag is only one of several suggestions to the search engine about how they should process and display results.
the others are

- **301, 302 redirects**
- registering a canonical domain with web master tools
- probably others that I have missed

Note:

- The canonicalisation issues applies to all web **pages and URL's** - not just the domain.
- It affects page rank - whether you consider page rank to be important these day's I guess is a different issue, but your page rank will be split across the URL variations.

> I just don't wAnt to be negatively impacted for duplicate content.

Learn about canonicalisation, and then get your website structured properly.
The concept is pretty simple but its practical implementations are pretty involved and too much to try and explain here.
Personally I had to read like 10 blog articles and watch several Matt Cutts videos before I really understood how it all worked.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Michael. I'll leave it alone for now.

Comment: great, if this answer was useful, you can click the big "tick" so that others with the same question can know it helped.